# PostgreSQL database converts my chars from perl to a weird format

Tags: perl, postgresql, encoding

I am having a problem when i update an entry in my postgresql database, it converts my charcters to the wrong format. The way I update is:

```
use Encode;
...
$user_name = escapeSql($user_name); # a statement that to doese this: line 1: $s =~ s/\?/_/g; and line 2: $s =~ s/\*/%/g;
$user_name = decode("utf-8", $user_name);
...
$statement = "UPDATE person SET name='".$user_name."', email='".$user_email."' WHERE id='".$user_id."'"; # The real statement have some more attributes, buts its the name that errors.
print STDERR "Statement: ". $statement;
$sth = $dbh->prepare($statement);
$result = $sth->execute();
```

As you see, I print out the statement to check the user_name looks like it should and here is what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see its says "Thør Åstrüp Pédersen" which is my name where i have replaced some chars with the special chars im trying to insert/update my entry to. Now the big problem which i have been debugging for some days now, is when i make a select statement on the database and fetch my user_name to see if the new name (entered in a web-GUI using dojo) was changed and updated correctly.. but it looks like:

[image]

I simply cannot figure out why my database dose that or how i, in any way, could check what charcter encoding the database is set to and make the right conversion. But then again, it looks good in PERL since the error log outputs it correctly (as showen above in the first img), but the PostgreSQL database hates it and converts it for some reason to crappy chars.

I really hope someone can help, even though its not the first time i have met encoding problems.. but the first time I couldn't figure out since it looks like its a PostgreSQL thing and not Perl or PHP problem.

Comment: Your screenshots look like Windows commandline. Maybe you just don't have a proper codepage that displays UTF characters correctly. Can you try to display the data with a different SQL client?

Comment: (I don't really have an answer, but still) why not use placeholders (`UPDATE stack SET over = ? WHERE flow = ? AND com = ?`). Homegrown SQL escapes == [Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) in the future.

Comment: i have a web page displaying it correctly.. but i actually don't care how the webpage displays it.. its how its saved in the db. I can't show you in another client since its on a server and linux-terminal is the only thing i have access to... but from answer 1 i can see its SQL_ANSII the db is encoded to and my webpage is UTF-8... so i can see a problem there.

Comment: Dallaylaen.. the reason is, its not the best designed system so i had to make due with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check your database encoding via issuing \l in psql prompt. You can also check your client encoding with 'show client_encoding;'

It's maybe better to recreate database in UTF8. Everything about encodings in PostgreSQL is explained [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/multibyte.html).

Comment: Nice, checking if it works... as for now i can see the encoding is set to SQL_ANSII, so thanks for that input already. Ill come back if it works.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! When i found out the db was encoded as SQL_ASCII it was pretty forward to find out a way to convert it correctly... even though my solution is ugly as balls :P 
Solution: My saved text was formatted weird from the start, so what i had to do was, encode to utf-8, convert all special chars to their HTML-representation, and then convert that string to ASCII. This worked!

Comment: Hey again.. celebrated to quickly.. it still wont display properly. Tried with encode("ascii", $user_name) and though that workd as explained above, but it didn't :/

Comment: haha doh! found the answer (with a ref to this site http://openacs.org/forums/message-view?message_id=190333) and the only thing i had to do was use encode("ISO8859-1", $user_name) after decoding the utf8 string, instead for encode("ascii", $user_name). Plus now i don't need to use the HTML::Entities module :D

Comment: and the reason why i don't migrate from ASCII to UTF8 is becuase i am developing on a test environment. The production environment uses this ASCII db and is way to big to migrate or convert (also the reason i ended in this problem to begin with, since i no way in hell would create any db or code file encoded in ascii)... Thanks again for that little input that made my day! <3